# Multiple feedback bandpass filter calculations are wrong when C1 and C2 are different values

Tags: filter, active-filter

I wrote a simple Python program to calculate a single MFB bandpass filter and I am getting different values for Q and bandwidth if the C1 and C2 are totally different values.  If I check with a different calculator, but the issue doesn't happen when C1 = C2.  I do know that C1 & C2 are usually the same value when a MFB bandpass is calculated.  Is it possible to use different values for C1 & C2?

I am thinking that if C1 & C2 aren't the same value, that the Q formula changes. The formulas for the center frequency and the gain always give the correct value.  The bandwidth is only calculated wrong due to Q being used to calculate it. I am guessing that this online filter calculator could be wrong.

My program uses the following formulas:

**center frequency**  = (1 / (2 * pi)) * sqrt((1 / (R3 * C1 * C2)) * ((1 / R1) + (1 / R2)))

**gain** = ((R3 / R1) * (C2 / (C1 + C2)))

**Q**  = (1/2) * square root(R3 / ((R1 * R2) / (R1 + R2)))

**Bandwidth** = center frequency / Q

I compared my program against this calculator : http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuBakeisan.htm

[image: online MFB bandpass calculator tool]

This is the output of my calculator using Python :

[image: My calculator programmed in python]

Comment: Where did you get your formulas?

Comment: @Andyaka The Gain and center frequency formula is from that online calculator , and the Q formula is a conversion of another formula from another website, the original formula for Q is (1/2) * square root(R3 / R1) when R1 = R1A & R1B in parallel. R1A & R1A in my calculator and the online calculator is R1 & R2.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's analyze [this](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuBakeisan.htm) circuit:

[image]

The transfer function is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle-\frac{\text{s}}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_1}}{\displaystyle\text{s}^2+\frac{\text{s}}{\text{R}_3}\left(\frac{1}{\text{C}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_2}\right)+\frac{1}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3}\left(\frac{1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_2}\right)}\tag1$$

Now, we want to solve for the value that \$\displaystyle\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\$ is at a maximum:

$$\frac{\partial\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|}{\partial\hat{\omega}}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\hat{\omega}=\dots\tag2$$

Solving this gives:

$$\hat{\omega}=\sqrt{\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\tag3$$

At the maximum we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{\text{C}_2\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)}\tag4$$

So, the cut-off frequency can be solved:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\text{C}_2\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega=\dots\tag5$$

Which gives:

$$\omega_\pm=\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)^2+\frac{4\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}}\pm\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)}{\displaystyle2\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3}\tag6$$

So, the bandwidth is given by:

$$\mathcal{B}:=\left|\omega_+-\omega_-\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3}\tag7$$

And the quality factor is given by:

$$\mathcal{Q}:=\frac{\hat{\omega}}{\mathcal{B}}=\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3}}=\frac{1}{\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}}\tag8$$

---

Notice that when \$\text{C}_1=\text{C}_2:=\text{C}\$, everything simplifies:

- $$\hat{\omega}=\frac{1}{\text{C}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\tag9$$
- $$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_3}{2\text{R}_1}\tag{10}$$
- $$\omega_\pm=\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\text{R}_3\left(\frac{1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_2}\right)+1}\pm1}{\text{CR}_3}\tag{11}$$
- $$\mathcal{B}=\frac{2}{\text{CR}_3}\tag{12}$$
- $$\mathcal{Q}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt{\text{R}_3\left(\frac{1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_2}\right)}\tag{13}$$

---

Notice that when \$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=\text{R}_3:=\text{R}\$ and \$\text{C}_1=\text{C}_2:=\text{C}\$, everything simplifies:

- $$\hat{\omega}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\text{CR}}\tag{14}$$
- $$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{1}{2}\tag{15}$$
- $$\omega_\pm=\frac{\sqrt{3}\pm1}{\text{CR}}\tag{16}$$
- $$\mathcal{B}=\frac{2}{\text{CR}}\tag{17}$$
- $$\mathcal{Q}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tag{18}$$

---

You can use my Mathematica-code down below to execute the calculations from above:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
R1 =(*give here your value for R1*); R2 =(*give here your value for \
R2*); R3 =(*give here your value for R3*); C1 =(*give here your value \
for C1*); C2 =(*give here your value for C2*); s = I*\[Omega];
h = (-s/(C1*
       R1))/(s^2 + (s/
        R3)*((1/C1) + (1/C2)) + (1/(C1*C2*R3))*((1/R1) + (1/R2)));
H = FullSimplify[
   Sqrt[ComplexExpand[Re[h]]^2 + ComplexExpand[Im[h]]^2], 
   Assumptions -> \[Omega] >= 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && 
     C1 > 0 && C2 > 0];
Subscript[\[Omega], max] = 
  FullSimplify[\[Omega] /. 
    Solve[{D[H, \[Omega]] == 0, \[Omega] >= 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && 
        R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0}, \[Omega]][[1]], 
   Assumptions -> R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0];
Subscript[H, max] = 
  FullSimplify[H /. \[Omega] -> Subscript[\[Omega], max], 
   Assumptions -> R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0];
Subscript[\[Omega], cutoff1] = 
  FullSimplify[\[Omega] /. 
    Solve[{H == Subscript[H, max]*(1/Sqrt[2]), \[Omega] >= 0 && 
        R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && 
        C2 > 0}, \[Omega]][[1]], 
   Assumptions -> R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0];
Subscript[\[Omega], cutoff2] = 
  FullSimplify[\[Omega] /. 
    Solve[{H == Subscript[H, max]*(1/Sqrt[2]), \[Omega] >= 0 && 
        R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && 
        C2 > 0}, \[Omega]][[2]], 
   Assumptions -> R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0];
B = FullSimplify[
   Abs[Subscript[\[Omega], cutoff1] - Subscript[\[Omega], cutoff2]], 
   Assumptions -> R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0];
Q = FullSimplify[Subscript[\[Omega], max]/B, 
   Assumptions -> R1 > 0 && R2 > 0 && R3 > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0];
Print["The maximum frequency is given by: ", Subscript[\[Omega], max],
   " rad/sec", " with \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \(max\)]\) = ", 
  Subscript[H, max], 
  " and cut-off frequencies \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\),     \
\(cutoff1\)]\) = ", Subscript[\[Omega], cutoff1], " rad/sec", 
  " and \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(cutoff2\)]\) = ", 
  Subscript[\[Omega], cutoff2], " rad/sec", " with bandwidth = ", B, 
  " rad/sec", " and quality factor = ", Q, "."];
If[And[Internal`RealValuedNumericQ[R1], 
  Internal`RealValuedNumericQ[R2], Internal`RealValuedNumericQ[C1], 
  Internal`RealValuedNumericQ[C2]], 
 Print["The maximum frequency is given by: ", 
  N[Subscript[\[Omega], max]], " rad/sec", 
  " with \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \(max\)]\) = ", 
  N[Subscript[H, max]], 
  " and cut-off frequencies \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\),     \
\(cutoff1\)]\) = ", N[Subscript[\[Omega], cutoff1]], " rad/sec", 
  " and \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(cutoff2\)]\) = ", 
  N[Subscript[\[Omega], cutoff2]], " rad/sec", " with bandwidth = ", 
  N[B], " rad/sec", " and quality factor = ", N[Q], 
  "."], " In order to give approximate values, choose values for \
resistors and capacitors. "]
```